# Trying to remove extra lines break in a CSV-like string using Javascript and Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in a textarea, representing a CSV file :

```
6166;14/12/2011;CASTANIE    Bernard;11, rue  Porte Bouqueyre;;33330;;Pose d'un radiateur dans la véranda.;44.31;
6167;14/12/2011;CASTANIE    Bernard;11, rue  Porte Bouqueyre;;33330;;Dépannage de la chaudière DE DIETRICH MCR 24.;50.23;
6301;07/02/2012;SCI    DU    MANOIR;Le   Manoir -   BP  33;;33330;jfxxxxxxx@gmail.com;"DEPANNAGE PLOMBERIE
Intervention R12020023 du 20/01/12";895.16;
6302;07/02/2012;SCI    DU    MANOIR;Le   Manoir -   BP  33;;33330;jfxxxxxxx@gmail.com;"DEPANNAGE PLOMBERIE WC des bureaux.
Intervention R12020024 du 23/01/12";92.86;
```

Some of these lines have a line break in the fields.

What would be the regex that I could use in Javascript to remove them and only keep the last line break?

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
myString.replace(/[\r\n]+([^;])/gm,"")
```

Big thanks in advance!

Sam

Comment: Hi, the customer asked me to remove them. These are lines to be imported in another external tool. He wants these breaks to be replaced by a " "

Comment: You can use the csv package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv and map each value with a simple replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all newlines which are not preceded by semicolon:

```
myString.replace(/([^;])\n/g, '$1 ')
```

Comment: Tried but got this as a result : 6166;14/12/2011;CASTANIE    Bernard;11, rue  Porte Bouqueyre;;33330;;Pose d'un radiateur dans la véranda.;44.31;167;14/12/2011;CASTANIE    Bernard;11, rue  Porte Bouqueyre;;33330;;Dépannage de la chaudière DE DIETRICH MCR 24.;50.23;301;07/02/2012;SCI    DU    MANOIR;Le   Manoir -   BP  33;;33330;jfxxxxxxx@gmail.com;"DEPANNAGE PLOMBERIEntervention R12020023 du 20/01/12";895.16;302;07/02/2012;SCI    DU    MANOIR;Le   Manoir -   BP  33;;33330;jfxxxxxxx@gmail.com;"DEPANNAGE PLOMBERIE WC des bureaux.ntervention R12020024 du 23/01/12";92.86;

Comment: All the newlines were replaced and I loose the first following character

Comment: yes because `[^;]` matches all non ; characters and replaces them  with nothing, you could add ";" on the right side or directly use a look-behind (see other answer)

Comment: I would recommend to replace \r too

Comment: @Kodakgold + madox I'm afraid it won't work with cells beginning with "\n" :-/

Comment: @procrastinator right, better solution would be to join all lines and split it by certain count of delimiters

Comment: Ok, good idea. I removed all the blank lines before running the regexp. It worked. Thanks guys !

Comment: @procrastinator Neither do I, just take it easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that the following function works (probably faster than a regular expression):

```js
function cleanCSV (cols, csv) {
  var i, clean = "", col = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    switch (csv[i]) {
      case '\n' : if (col < cols) break;
      case ';'  : col = (col + 1) % (cols + 1);
      default   : clean += csv[i];
    }
  }
  return clean;
}

document.write(
  "<pre>" + 
  cleanCSV(3, ""
    + "a;\nb;c;  \n"
    + "d;e\n;f;\n"
    + "g;h\ni;j;\n"
  )
  + "</pre>"
);
```